# async and await C# - Bug?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

These two snippets of code take different amount of time to finish, why? The first one takes 3000ms, while the second one takes only 2000ms. I am running .Net framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();            

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
        sw2.Start();

        Task<int> t1 = GetList();
        Task<int> t2 = GetList2();

        var a = await t1;
        var b = await t2;

    }).Wait();

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Second snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();            

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
        sw2.Start();

        var a = await GetList();
        var b = await GetList2();

    }).Wait();

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you expect to happen, why, and what actually happens? It's almost never a bug in the framework, so expect that either your expectations or your code are wrong.

Comment: `var a = await GetList();` waits while `GetList` completes.

Comment: What do you mean with 2000ms pause? Where should this pause come from?

Comment: *Shouldn't both examples result in a 2000 ms pause* ? Umm what?? Where does that magical number comes from?

Comment: It doesn't help that we don't have `GetList` or `GetList2` - it sounds like you're probably just seeing the difference between starting two tasks and then awaiting both (which means the second gets to run while we're waiting for the first) vs start/await, start/await which means the second task only gets to start *after* the first has finished.

Comment: How are you profiling it? Do you build in release? How long do each GetList and GetList2 take on their own?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are asking for execution time difference.
Because this would be sync call

```
var a = await GetList();
var b = await GetList2();
```

first GetList completes and then GetList2 completes so there is execution time difference.

and in the below case:

```
    Task<int> t1 = GetList();
    Task<int> t2 = GetList2();

    var a = await t1;
    var b = await t2;
```

GetList and GetList2 will be running in parallel and then you said to wait for first one and then for the second one.

Comment: While you are right about the first example, your statement about the second one is not completely correct. The execution behavior strongly depends on the implementation of `GetList()`. If there is no `await` or similar statement that causes an early return, `GetList2()` will be executed only when `GetList()` completes. Therefore, everything before the first `await` in `GetList()` does not run concurrently.

Comment: Yes agreed with you. Need to update my answer. Thanks for point out to it.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the code below kicks off both asynchronous actions **and then** starts waiting. So they both execute in parallel and then you wait for the first one and once that is finished you wait for the second one.

```
Task<int> t1 = GetList();
Task<int> t2 = GetList2();

var a = await t1;
var b = await t2;
```

The second example only starts the second action once the first one is completed, so there is no overlap at all

```
var a = await GetList();
var b = await GetList2();
```